# Progress bar dialog is not working with FTP uploading in android

Tags: android-asynctask, ftp, progressdialog

In Asynctask,either the progress bar is working or file is uploading successfully.
COMMENT2 line upload file properly when we write before the COMMENT1 line but progress bar is not working.
 But if we write COMMENT2 after COMMENT1 then we face ERROR code 500(Syntax error) and uploading failed but progress bar
 works properly.

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize = 1024,progress;
 byte[] buffer;

 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading file..");
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // connection();
    FTPClient con = null;

      try
      {
          con = new FTPClient();
          con.connect(FTP_HOST);

          if (con.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS))
          {
              con.enterLocalActiveMode(); // important!
              con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
              con.changeWorkingDirectory("/uploads/school-staging/files/");
              String data = FilePath;
              final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
              BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(data));
              int bufferSize=1024;
              byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
              // Read file

              bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);//COMMENT 1
              progress=0;

              System.out.println("BYTE READ="+bytesRead);

              while (bytesRead > 0)
              {   

                  progress+=bytesRead;
                  System.out.println("PROGRESS="+progress);
                  out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                  bytesAvailable = in.available(); 
                  publishProgress((int)((progress*100)/(file.length())));
                  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, bufferSize);

                  bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

              }
            boolean result = con.storeFile(FileName, in);//COMMENT 2
              int code= con.getReplyCode();
                      System.out.println("CODE="+code);
              in.close();
              publishProgress(100); 

              if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
              System.out.println("RESULT="+result);
              con.logout();
              con.disconnect();  
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

    return "ok";
}

@Override
 public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }//end of onProgressUpdate


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    connection();
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem. The reason for this seems to be that the ui code in onPreExecute() doesnt get to render by android system, and code in doInBackground() occupies the cpu. You can dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute() though...

You'd have to show the progress dialog before creating AsyncCaller, pass the progress dialog to AsyncCaller and you can dismiss it in onPostExecute().

```
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setTitle("title string");
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.show();

    new AsyncCaller(getActivity(), pd).execute(params);

   in onPostExecute():
      if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
```